# Can't locate object method "new" via package Email::Sender

Tags: perl

There have been several similar threads in this vein, but seems like the usual culprit has been that the person forgot to install or `use` the relevant package. Doesn't quite seem so in this case. I double-checked to make sure [`Email::Sender`](https://metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aSender) was installed

```
cpan[1]> install Email::Sender
Going to read '/home/ajmills/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 18 Jan 2013 07:07:06 GMT
Email::Sender is up to date (0.120002).

cpan[2]>
```

My simple program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Email::Sender;

my $mailer = Email::Sender->new( {
    mailer => 'SMTP::TLS',
    mailer_args => [
        Host => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        Port => 587,
        User => 'xxx@gmail.com',
        Password => 'xxx',
        Hello => 'xxx.org',
    ]
} );
```

And then running it:

```
:~$ perl email.pl 
Can't locate object method "new" via package "Email::Sender" at email.pl line 5.
```

Any idea?

Comment: It appears you are reading the documentation for `Email::Send`, which is a very different module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure, but the docs say to call Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new.

```
try {
    sendmail(
      $message,
      {
        from => $SMTP_ENVELOPE_FROM_ADDRESS,
        transport => Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new({
            host => $SMTP_HOSTNAME,
            port => $SMTP_PORT,
        })
      }
    );
  } catch {
      warn "sending failed: $_";
  };
```

http://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender

Comment: Aggh! Yes I tried this and it works. I was probably looking at an outdated example.